# DHT11 and DHT22 unused pin

Tags: temperature-sensor

The DHT11 and DHT22 is a 4 pin temperature and humidity sensor, where one of the pins is labelled as NC (not connected).

I'm curious what the unused pin is used for.
Factory calibration?

Comment: I have [wondered the same](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/humidity-sensors/), however I think that is just is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the DHT11 it's connected to pin 6 of the SOIC14 inside. So it's at least connected to something. But who knows what it's for.

It has a (internal) pull-up resistor to VCC of around 100kOhm on this pin.

I connected my logic analyzer to it, there is no signal, even while reading the sensor. Also connecting the arduino's signal wire to this (incorrect) pin does nothing.

Factory calibration or testing would be my guess too, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

in this datasheet both 3. and 4. pins are marked GND :
https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital%20humidity%20and%20temperature%20sensor%20AM2302.pdf

Comment: Only on the DHT22.